# How to target table with ID?

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

I am using datatables and using below css to hide the header of the table.

```
table.dataTable thead {
    display: none;
}
```

Now what is happening is I have two tables with id as `userList1` & `userList2`.

What I want to do is apply this css for only table with id as `userList1`.

Any idea how to get this done?

I tried

```
#userList1.table.dataTable thead {
    display: none;
}

#userList1 > table.dataTable thead {
    display: none;
}
```

but none is working.

I am not sure whether above is right or wrong, but I tried. I am newbie for CSS.

---

HTML Code is

**Table 1**

```
<table id="userList" class="responsive dataTable" dir="LTR" style="width: 100%;border: 0px;" aria-describedby="userList_info">
```

**Table 2**

```
<table id="userList:2:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>
<table id="userList:1:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>
<table id="userList:0:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>
```

Note : I have two table..

Table 1 have inner tables as table 2...

So table I have is

```
<table id="userList" class="responsive dataTable" dir="LTR" style="width: 100%;border: 0px;" aria-describedby="userList_info">

    <table id="userList:2:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>
    <table id="userList:1:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>
    <table id="userList:0:userList2" class="responsive appointments" dir="LTR"></table>

</table>
```

Note I am using JSF language and inner table ids are created by JSF...

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gku7r/)

Comment: Here `#userList1.dataTable thead ` or just `#userList1 thead ` your original code does not work because `table` is not a class so `#userList1.table` targets nothing. If these don't work then you will need to provide the table markup. Just the table tag is fine, don't need the guts of it

Comment: Try `table#userList1.dataTable thead`

Comment: Please provide the example of your HTML

Comment: @Vucko : both tables hiding header...

Comment: Why not just `#userList1 thead {display: none;}` ?

Comment: @FahimParkar [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/3KXyL/)?

Comment: One of the problems is the dot in `#userList1.table` as that is used to select a class, not a tag.

Comment: @Vucko : my mistake... can you give me solution for the updated questions?

Comment: @FahimParkar and what are you trying to hide inside that main table (`#userList`)?

Comment: main table I am not using header, but for inner tables I am using header to show date...

Comment: @FahimParkar and you want to hide _all_ inner table headers or of some specific inner table?

Comment: @Vucko : I want to hide outer table header...

Comment: `#userList>thead{...}` ?

Comment: @Vucko : still not working... I think the big reason is `userList` is present in second id tooo..

Comment: Next time it'd be really nice if you updated with the HTML you're actually using instead of updating it multiple times.

Comment: @Vucko : yes, but why its not working at my end then?

Comment: @FahimParkar check your HTML source(crtl+u in browser), maybe it's rendering differently.

Comment: @Vucko : grrrr... i don't why but it is working now... thanks mate for help...

Comment: @FahimParkar, we cannot know why it is working at your end because we cannot see. Your jsfiddle apparently does not correspond to what you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the header of the outer table:

```
#userList thead {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide *all* of the headers of the inner table:

```
#userList table thead {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide the header of one of the inner tables, based on @steveax's solution:

```
#userList #userList\:2\:userList2 thead {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: @FahimParkar which ever table you are trying to target, just do `#tableID thead` and you are good to go

Comment: if I use your code, inside tables header also getting hided... see my question again please, I have updated code.. see the inner tables id... I think that is causing problem...

Comment: My code is generating ids like that.. I am not generating... I am using JSF and its generating ids like that...

Comment: please check updated question one more time.. I have made it simple and clear... see how I have table at the end...

Comment: I cannot control JSF... as those are inner tables, jsf is creating ids like that... any solution for this?

Comment: [`id` selectors can indeed include colons, you just have to escape them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592488/557612) (`\:`)

Comment: @steveax Ah forgive me, I'm completely mistaken. Had no clue you can escape colors, let alone other special characters.

Comment: @jonsuh : I want to hide the main table header only... I don't want to hide inner tables header... just main outer table header...

Comment: @FahimParkar Pick and choose one of the appropriate suggestions

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#userlist.dataTable thead {
display:none;
}
```

and you shuold use display:none; only for headers that you want to hide it.

for hiding only one thead you can use inline styles.

```
    <table id="userList" class="dataTable" border="1">
        <thead style="display:none;">
            <tr>
                <td>This is what I want to hide</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gku7r/4/)**

Comment: you can edit your HTML and use inline styles.i edited the answer.